# how to change dataframes using a loop in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have N dataframes ranging from L1...Ln.

I would like to modify them to keep rows pertaining to a certain condition.

I ran the following loop:

```
for df in [L1,...,Ln]:
    df=df.ix[df['Sector']=='Services']
```

However, when I call out each dataframe, I find it has not been replaced accordingly. How do I modify a set of dataframes using a loop?

I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite the old dataframe with the new one:

```
all_dfs = [L1,...,Ln]
# iterate through the dataframes one by one
# keep track of the order in index and the content in df 
for index, df in enumerate(all_dfs):
    # modify the current dataframe df 
    # then overwrite the old one in the same index. 
    all_dfs[index]= df.ix[df['Sector']=='Services']
```

Comment: Am I not doing so currently through df=df...?

Comment: @runawaykid you are overwriting the local variable df. but not the actual df in the list.

Comment: I find that I need to add the line [L1,...Ln] = all_dfs at the end for this to work when I call out L1. If not its still the original dataframe.

Comment: @runawaykid of course, because all_dfs is a copy of  [L1,...Ln]. In anycase, you have to assign your list  [L1,...Ln] to a variable and use the variable instead of the list..